# How do I run Android code every few seconds only when the app is open?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Currently, my app needs to do a task every 5 seconds, which involves updating the locations of markers in a Google Maps API-using map. However, it only really needs to do it every 5 seconds when the app is open and people are using it.

It seems that AsyncTask, according to people on the Internet, runs even when the app is closed, causing it to use up a lot of battery life.

How do I make it so that the task runs if and only if the app is open or just starting?

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url_select = "https://www.example.com/"; // generic

        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_select);
            HttpURLConnection connectTo = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connectTo.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
            connectTo.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connectTo.setDoInput(true);
            connectTo.connect();

            // Read content & Log
            inputStream = connectTo.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e4) {
            Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Convert response to string using String Builder
        try {
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            result = sBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("St.Build,BuffRead", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    } // protected Void doInBackground(String... params)

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        //parse JSON data
        try {
            JSONObject busData = new JSONObject(result);

            if (busData.getString("title").equals("Bus Positions")) {
                for (Marker mark: allBuses) {
                    mark.remove(); // Remove marker
                }
                allBuses.clear();
                JSONObject resultSet = busData.getJSONObject("ResultSet");
                JSONArray results = resultSet.getJSONArray("Result");
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject bus = results.getJSONObject(i);
                    double lat = bus.getDouble("lat");
                    double lng = bus.getDouble("lng");
                    int call_name = bus.getInt("call_name");
                    String bus_type = "bus";
                    LatLng busLocation = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                    Marker busMark = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(busLocation)
                            .title(bus_type)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.id.action_search)));
                    allBuses.add(busMark);

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
        } // catch (JSONException e)

    } // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some workarounds to create a long running asynctask and manage its life cycle accordingly to the life cycle of the activity.

```
You can cancel the AsyncTask in the onStop method of you Activity.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my searches across the web I saw a few different approaches and wanted to know what is the best way of doing this.

Best way to schedule a server call?

the options I saw were:

**1. Timer**
**2. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor**

```
                  ***Timer***






int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec

int period = 1000; // repeat every sec

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

public void run() {

// // call your MyAsyncTask class

          }

     }, delay, period);

}
```

*Timer has some drawbacks that are solved by ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.
*

```
           ***ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.***


ScheduledExecutorService   executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Log.d("EXESER", "CH EXES");
                    // Your code


                }
            });
        }
    }, 1
```

0, 40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

what's your opinion?